# Weird TFS Powershell cmdlet behaviour

Tags: powershell, tfs

I have 2 machines both with Power tools 2012. The following command works like it is supposed to on my local machine but does not return anything

```
(Get-TfsItemHistory "$MyItemspec").Changes
```

Any ideas? The folder structure is exactly the same on both the machines.

Comment: I think you're saying this returns the item history on your computer, but on another computer it returns nothing?  Are you running as the same user on both computers?  Does `Get-TfsItemHistory` return the same thing (without the `.Changes`)?

Comment: I am running as different users on the machines. Get-TfsItemHistory does return the same stuff on both the machines.

Comment: Then the issue may be permissions.  Try running as the same user on both machines (or different users on the same machine).  Perhaps one user does not have rights to view the item history.

Comment: Does not work with the same user (the one that works on my box) on the other machine. Both the user accounts are admins in TFS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running PSH 3 on one machine and V2 on another? V3 automatically applies properties that don't apply to the collection to each member.

On PSH V2 if `Get-TfsItemHistory` returns multiple results then `.Changes` will be null (no such property on a .NET array), but in V3 it will be applied to each of the objects. To get the same effect in V2:

```
Get-TfsItemHistory $MyItemspec | % {$_.Changes}
```